# Konvajs Cancel Drag event

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I'm using dragBoundFunc to limit the drag movement but in certain distance I want to cancel the drag, the idea is the object would drop automatically when user try to move to far position.

I tryed using `event.preventDefault()` but it doesn't work.

How can I achieve that?

```
var image1 = new Konva.Image({
  image: imageObj,
  x: limit.left,
  y: limit.top,
  width: gBoxSize ,
  height: gBoxSize ,
  name: 'gameobj',
  draggable: true,

  dragBoundFunc: function(pos,event) {
      var newPos = {x: pos.x, y: pos.y};

      // if newPos exceeds 200px I want force to cancel the drag
      if(Math.abs(prevPos.x - newPos.x) > 200){
         // ?
      }

      if(newPos.x <= limit.left){
          newPos.x = limit.left;
      }else if(newPos.x >= limit.right){
          newPos.x = limit.right;
      }

      if(newPos.y <= limit.top){
          newPos.y = limit.top;
      }else if(newPos.y >= limit.bottom){
          newPos.y = limit.bottom;
      }

      // do some stuffs

      return newPos;
  }            
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `node.stopDrag()` method for that case:

```
if(Math.abs(prevPos.x - newPos.x) > 200){
  image1.stopDrag();
}
```

But it may be better to use `dragmove` event to check that condition and stop drag from it.